# How to implement a pipeline?

Tags: c#

The idea of this module is the be able to graphically represent data inside of a pipeline.
For example, data can look like this:

```
1,4
```

This would be a `function y=f(x)`, where:

```
4=f(1)
```

I need to use this line

`TODO: WritePointToHTML(rawData);`

The basic idea of this is to generate HTML file, with code which will draw required line.

I tried to draw a line using html, but I am not able to understand how to represent it in a pipeline

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Comment: This question is very confusing, is it for school? It sounds like a homework question. Without doing the assignment for you it seems like we're missing some information to be able to help you. One thing I will say is that the word `pipeline` in this context may be referring to a `rendering pipeline`. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/webgl/webgl_graphics_pipeline.htm

Comment: But you may want to just generate an SVG Line tag with the given points. Here is the API for that: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_line.asp

Comment: If you have more than two points then try drawing a Path https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_path.asp And if you want to do it dynamically then you can use a canvas object like you have shown above which has a similar API using `.beginPath` https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_beginpath.asp

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that the original poster is looking to draw lines, not use c# pipelines.

```
var can;
var ctx;

function init(){
  can=document.getElementById("Canvas");
  ctx=can.getContext("2d");
  ctx.canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
  ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  DrawSlope(1,20);
}

function DrawSlope(x,y)
{
   var firstPoint = [x,0];
   var secondPoint = [1,x+y];

WritePointToHTML(firstPoint[0],firstPoint[1],secondPoint[0],secondPoint[1]);
}

function WritePointToHTML(x,y,xTwo,yTwo)
{
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x, y);
ctx.lineTo(xTwo, yTwo);
ctx.stroke();
}
```

// added "draw slope" to factor in slope formula.
https://codepen.io/hollyeplyler/pen/gqYyZx

Comment: Noted, added in "draw slope" to create that functionality.

Comment: Actually i have to create a html page to draw line charts and using c#code we have to change the x and y-axis values and show the chart

Comment: You're using pipelines for an html page? We probably need more details about the specifics then. This code could still work. Use the C# to get the data, then draw it with this code.

Comment: code is working fine. but i want x-axis and y-axis and we can change data through c# code.

Comment: This would be a function y=f(x). I.E
4=f(1),
2=f(6)
etc.

This should be painted. But, we can also have following example, where we have 4 features and one label:
f1,f2,f3,f4,label
1,2,4,5,1
1,2,4,5,1
1,2,4,5,1
1,2,4,5,1
In this case module needs a configuration like: Show me l=f(f3) where fq,f2 and f4 = const.
Also graph with representing function of feature 3 by all other constant values.
So, configuration should define both variables: y and x as index in data[] array.

api.UseDrawingModule(x=2, y=4)
2 is for index 2 of feature 3. 4 is index of label.